# (tf2/tf.keras) How could # params decreases when a model contains another model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a keras Model(not Layer) named Model A. Model A contains keras.Layers of types: Dense, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, add, GlobalAveragePooling2D.

The output of model.summary() is as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
layer_type_1 (Layer_type_1)  multiple                  3776      
_________________________________________________________________
...                           ...                      ...
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                multiple                  1024      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,787,808
Trainable params: 4,782,496
Non-trainable params: 5,312
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have another keras model (model B) which **contains** model A.

summary():

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              multiple                  35        
_________________________________________________________________
model_A (ModelA)             multiple                  4787232   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,787,267
Trainable params: 4,781,955
Non-trainable params: 5,312
_________________________________________________________________
```

I wonder how could the number of total parameters in model B is **less** than model A?

Since model B contains model A, it must be greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it's because the input shape (to the model A) is changed from (W, D, 6) to (W, D, 5) due to the first Conv2D layer in model B.